# WhatsApp c# api "Login Failed" message

Tags: c#, api, whatsapp

i'm using c# api for whatsapp

and when i attempt to send a message to any number , the message ""Login Failed" show up to me !!

here's my code

```
  string to = textBox1.Text;
        string mes = richTextBox1.Text;
        string from = ******************";
        WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(from, Mypass, "56mmkjkjk", true, true);

        wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
        { 
            Console.WriteLine("Connected");
            wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Connection success!");
                wa.SendMessage(to, "Hello World!");
                Console.WriteLine("Message sent!");
            };
            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {
               MessageBox.Show("Login failed: {0}", data);
            };
           wa.Login();
        };
        wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Connect failed: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
        };
        wa.Connect();

        Console.WriteLine("END");
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Answer (score 3):

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BwBxpfm3kmmgNGtKNkRTRF9fS0k/view?pli=1
 use this dll this worked for me , try to use a new whats app no , freshly registered from wart

code used was

```
      WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp(sender, password, nickname, true, true);
      wa.OnConnectSuccess += () => {
        Console.WriteLine("Connected");
        wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phoneNumber, data) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Connection success!");
            wa.SendMessage(target, "testing C# Api,sent via C#");
            Console.WriteLine("Message sent!");
        };
        wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) => {
            Console.WriteLine("Login failed: {0}", data);
        };
        wa.Login();
      };
      wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) => {
        Console.WriteLine("Connect failed: {0}", ex.StackTrace);
      };
      wa.Connect();
      Console.WriteLine("END");
```

Comment: What is different about this DLL?
Can you provide the source for it?

Answer (score -1):

To all of you who gets Login failed Not Authorized i foun out what the problem is.
After you get the password from wart you need to Varefy the whatsapp in your phone .
The catch is when you varpy its is changing you password so dont varepy.
if you want to send whatsapp mesages from c# you need to secrapies your whatapp or you can get another number.
So remember dont Vefiy!!!!﻿