# Sending WhatsApp Messages from c# Applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, whatsapp

I want to send WhatsApp message to any number from ASP.NET web form. I can't able to send a message using WhatsApp API, Still I got login issue and connection failed.Can you please suggest any alternate way to access WhatsApp in my site…

I tried below code...

```
 public string Watsapp()
    {
        string status="";
        WhatsApp wa = new WhatsApp("919****", "IMEINo", "Gopi3", false, false);
        wa.OnConnectSuccess += () =>
        {
            status="connect";
            wa.OnLoginSuccess += (phno, data) =>
            {
                wa.SendMessage("917*****", "Hi This is Gopinath");
            };

            wa.OnLoginFailed += (data) =>
            {
              status="login failed" + data;
            };
            wa.Login();
        };
        wa.OnConnectFailed += (ex) =>
        {
           status="connection failed";
        }
            ;

        wa.Connect();

        return status;

    }
```

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: WhatApp API is library name

Comment: Is it [this](https://github.com/mgp25/Chat-API-NET) ? Because that's not official, and I'm pretty sure there isn't an official API client. It's possible WhatsApp have changed their API to block that kind of unofficial client (until it gets updated...). If it is ever updated, the last commit was 11 months ago.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31254529/whatsapp-c-sharp-api-login-failed-message) may resolve your issue.